# utf-8 and cp1254 encoding error in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, decoding

Even though I rename columns with İl (City) and İlçe (County) in a data to utf-8, I am getting the following error::

```
Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Ä°l', 'Ä°lÃ§e']
```

My code detects the Turkish letters İ and ç as 'Ä°' and 'Ã§'.

The whole project is written according to cp1254.

How can I fix İ and ç according to cp1254?

```
"ç".encode("utf8")
Output:b'\xc3\xa7'

b'\xc3\xa7'.decode("cp1254")
Output:'Ã§'

"İ".encode("utf8")
Output:b'\xc4\xb0'

b'\xc4\xb0'.decode("cp1254")
Output:'Ä°'
```

Data manipulation codes here:

```
def read_rakip_df(city_name, data_path):
        rename_cols = ["ID", "Marka", "İl", "İlçe", "Mahalle", "Mahalle Kodu", "Latitude", "Longitude"]
        use_cols = [
            "Nokta ID",
            "Kategori 5",
            "İl",
            "İlçe",
            "Mahalle",
            "Mahalle Kodu",
            "Latitude - Enlem - Y",
            "Longitude - Boylam - X",
        ]
        rename_fix = dict(zip(use_cols, rename_cols))
        df_rakip = pd.read_excel(data_path, usecols=use_cols)
        df_rakip.rename(columns=rename_fix, inplace=True)
        df_rakip.columns = [k.strip() for k in df_rakip.columns]
        df_rakip = df_rakip.loc[df_rakip["İl"] == city_name]
        df_rakip = df_rakip.copy().rename(
            columns={
                "Mahalle": "mahalle",
                "Mahalle Kodu": "mahalle_kodu",
                "Latitude": "latitude",
                "Longitude": "longitude",
                "Marka": "isim",
                "İl": "il",
                "İlçe": "ilce",
            }
        )
        df_rakip["latitude"] = df_rakip["latitude"].astype(float)
        df_rakip["longitude"] = df_rakip["longitude"].astype(float)
    
        return df_rakip
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about encodings. Perhaps review https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to correct encoding before passing column names to `read_excel()`

```
pd.read_excel(data_path, usecols=[s.encode("cp1254").decode("utf8") for s in use_cols])
```

However, I assume the main problem is that your python source has `# -*- coding: cp1254 -*-` declared, but the file itself is saved as UTF-8. If this is the case, the easiest is to fix the encodings: declared has to match the actual in which the file is saved.